# FileOutputStream writing strange characters

Tags: java, byte, fileoutputstream

I am trying to write a byte array to a file with a `FileOutputStream`like this:

```
public static void writeFileContents(String path, byte[] contents) {
    try(FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
        stream.write(contents);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where `contents` is populated like this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[32 * 32];
Arrays.fill(bytes, (byte) 2);
```

But I am receiving weird characters in the file, it is the letters 'STX' in a white box. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) equivalent of `(byte) 2` (or "Start of Text"). Like,

```
System.out.println((char) ((byte) 2));
```

and that is an unprintable character.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII codes 0 - 31 are control characters and have no defined displayable equivalent. You can view the full table here: http://www.asciitable.com/